# "An error occurred submitting the CAPTCHA" - EVERY TIME

Tags: support, bug

Having had the captcha pop up when posting, I've so far failed to persuade it that I'm human.

This is not a gripe about the difficulty of it, the frequency of popups, etc. it's the technical fact that EVERY time I submit the answer the ONLY response I get is:

**"An error occurred submitting the CAPTCHA"**

I have disabled EVERY security/privacy/adblock plugin in Firefox:

- Adblock Plus
- Ghostery
- Noscript
- Flashblock
- HTTPS Everywhere
- Firefox's inbuilt Mixed Content Blocking (XSS protection)

The Firebug console shows nothing error-wise, I've got no other plugins running, and the Captcha window gives no other feedback.

Comment: Just as an aside I joined here with 101 rep from SO and don't remember ever having to enter one. It'd also be interesting to know what triggers the captcha in the first place for a long-term / constructive user.

Comment: @PeterJ I get prompted to enter a CAPTCHA about once every alternate month, and also if I have left a partially written post overnight before submitting.

Comment: This question is well written.  I guess bot technology has gotten quite sophisticated.

Comment: Maybe I'm having an existential crisis and don't even realise it.

Comment: Have you tried any other browsers?

Comment: Same thing happened to me in Firefox as well.

Comment: @Anindo Ghosh Same thing is the main source of CAPTCHA for me as well.